# Whats the difference between reminder and note?

Tags: meaning

Definitions say reminder causes to bring to memory, notes are written down to aid memory.

My Apple dictionary says:

- note - a brief record of facts, topics, or thoughts written down as an aid to memory.
- reminder - a thing that causes someone to remember.

Also they describe the Apple notes app as an Apple app that lets you jot down things you want to remember, or keep photos and files handy.

Comment: _Definitions say_...which definitions are you using? You should include the details of your research to help clarify the question and to prevent people giving you information you already know.

Comment: Hint: What are the common characteristics in those definitions? What are not common to both?

Comment: If you write yourself a note, it reminds you or it can label things. But notes to others can be invites, warnings, thanks, instructions, explanations, recipes, reminders...

Comment: A "note" is some sort of written thingamabob.  A "reminder" is anything that reminds you -- could be a note, could be that you placed your shoes upside-down by the door, could be that you left your coat hanging on a door-knob.

Answer (score 2):

A "note" can be much more than an aid to memory.

I might write a note to the milkman*, to ask for an extra pint of milk.  I might write a note to my child's teacher to ask for a morning absence to visit a dentist.  I might write a note to summarise the key points of a book.  These are to help me remember, but they aren't "reminders" more of a "summary".  An academic might write a note to a journal to be published. The key to being a "note" is it is like a short *written* letter, which might be written to remind you of something later.

(Not to mention musical notes, and bank notes)

On the other hand, a reminder need not be written.  I can give a reminder to my child to take out the trash by speaking.

While a reminder could be in the form of a note,  it very often isn't.  While a note could function as a reminder, it could do lots of other things.

*<sub>Actually I won't because I haven't seen a milkman in about 30 years.</sub>